# Docker-compose two service cannot access each other. Connection refused

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, docker-compose, containers

I am new to docker, now I am trying to containerize my frontend and backend, React and Flask application.

I created my docker-compose file as following, I try to expose them on the same network.

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - BACKEND_URL=http://backend:5000
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=production
    ports:
      - "5005:5000"
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here's my frontend Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as a parent image
FROM node:16.13.2-alpine

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port on which the application will run
EXPOSE 3000

# Define the command to start the application
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and here is my backend dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python3", "-m", "flask", "run"]
```

In my front end code, I tried to access the backend host port 5000 with this code

```
axios.post(`http://backend:5000/deletecode`, {
                    'uuid': uuid,
                }, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
```

But I got a URL not found, and there's nothing return back to me.

Here's what I tried so far to resolve this issue.

1. I shell in to the front end container and PING the backend service, and got the response.

> ```
> /app # ping backend:5000
>
> PING backend:5000 (172.21.0.2): 56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.257 ms
> 64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.292 ms
> ```

2. I tried to send a URL request within the backend container, and got success

> ```
> # curl http://localhost:5000/test
>
> {
>   "message": "healthy response"
> }
> ```

3. I tried to curl the backend/test from my frontend shell, and it's be denied.

> /app # curl backend:5000/test
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to backend port 5000 after 1 ms: Connection refused

4. I tried to curl the backend/test on port 5005, which is the port exposed to the host, from the host terminal, and got empty response.

> shaopengliu@Shaopengs-MBP Evase % curl http://localhost:5005/test
> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Thanks for looking into this question thus far, if there's any suggestion of what I might doing wrong, or anything I could tried out, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that `axios.post()` call being made from code that's running in the browser?  The browser is not in a container and can't access the Docker-network host names.

Comment: I think you are right David. I modified the frontend code so that in the post method is not using the "backend" as the IP address, but using "localhost:5005", and it worked in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your compose.yml file:
whenever you specify a port to expose the syntax is: <host_port>:<container_port>, so in your case for the backed you are exposing the container port 5000 on the local port 5005 while your frontend is trying to connect to port 5000. To solve this problem you can simply change:

```
backend:
    build: ./backend
    environment:
       - FLASK_ENV=production
    ports:
       - "5000:5000"
    networks:
       - my-network
```

---- EDIT -----

Another option is leaving the current docker-compose configuration:

```
backend:
    build: ./backend
    environment:
       - FLASK_ENV=production
    ports:
       - "5005:5000"
    networks:
       - my-network
```

And then modify the frontend logic to connect the frontend to the port 5005 instead of port 5000:

```
axios.post(`http://backend:5005/deletecode`, {
                'uuid': uuid,
            }, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
```

This should solve your problem and allow use a different port for the backend (since the 5000 is already in use).

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I chose 5005 because my 5000 port is been taken by some other processes, which I don't know which process is using. When I try to kill that process, that process would restart itself with a different pid, but still taken over the port 5000. However, I think in my case, my frontend and backend should be in the same network, which in my limited knowledge, it wouldn't matter which port of backend is exposed to the host, the frontend would always see the backend service's 5000 As It. I tried to expose something like 5005:5005 as well, but didn't get progress as well

Comment: If you change the port to 5005:5005 you are not exposing correctly, remember the syntax that I explained in my reply (<host_port>:<container_port>). If you cannot bind the container to port 5000 because is used by another procession can leave the port to 5005 and then update accordingly the frontend code (I update my reply accordingly)